# Convert date-time string to class Date

Tags: r, date, lubridate, as.date, r-faq

I have a data frame with a character column of date-times.

When I use `as.Date`, most of my strings are parsed correctly, except for a few instances.  The example below will hopefully show you what is going on.

```
# my attempt to parse the string to Date -- uses the stringr package
prods.all$Date2 <- as.Date(str_sub(prods.all$Date, 1, 
                str_locate(prods.all$Date, " ")[1]-1), 
                "%m/%d/%Y")

# grab two rows to highlight my issue
temp <- prods.all[c(1925:1926), c(1,8)]
temp
#                    Date      Date2
# 1925  10/9/2009 0:00:00 2009-10-09
# 1926 10/15/2009 0:00:00 0200-10-15
```

As you can see, the year of some of the dates is inaccurate.  The pattern seems to occur when the day is double digit.

Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The reason you are getting the invalid 0200 date is that the character lengths of the day are different (two digits for 15-Oct, one digit for 9-Oct) - and your string substitute code is not accounting for that. At any rate you can probably use as.Date or strptime directly with the format agument, without processing the characters further.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You may be overcomplicating things, is there any reason you need the stringr package? You can use `as.Date` and its `format` argument to specify the *input* format of your string.

```
 df <- data.frame(Date = c("10/9/2009 0:00:00", "10/15/2009 0:00:00"))
 as.Date(df$Date, format =  "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
 # [1] "2009-10-09" "2009-10-15"
```

Note the **Details** section of `?as.Date`:

> Character strings are processed as far as necessary for the format specified: any trailing characters are ignored

Thus, this also works:

```
as.Date(df$Date, format =  "%m/%d/%Y")
# [1] "2009-10-09" "2009-10-15"
```

All the conversion specifications that can be used to specify the input `format` are found in the **Details** section in `?strptime`. Make sure that the *order* of the conversion specification as well as any *separators* correspond exactly with the format of your *input* string.

---

More generally and if you need the time component as well, use `as.POSIXct` or `strptime`:

```
as.POSIXct(df$Date, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")    
strptime(df$Date, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

I'm guessing at what your actual data might look at from the partial results you give.

Comment: I would caution against `strptime` because it returns a `POSIXlt` object, which tends to give new users fits because they don't realize it's a list.  If you need the time, use `as.POSIXct` but beware if your "dates" are really factors...

Comment: true, but since R 2.11.0 "length(<POSIXlt>) now returns the length of the corresponding abstract timedate-vector rather than always 9 (the length of the underlying list structure).  (Wish of PR#14073 and PR#10507.)" so I wondered if that was worth complicating things with. You can just as.POSIXct(strptime(x)) anyway.

Comment: I didn't realize that.  Thanks for the pointer.  Though I wonder if it could still be confusing if you have a `POSIXlt` column in a `data.frame`...

Comment: I realized after that it's not completely helpful - in a data.frame you will still get into trouble, though I think it's possible to put lists and arrays etc. in data.frames as columns. But I think better to understand the difference of lt/ct and use them carefully.

Comment: This seems misleading to me since the Date class that as.Date returns does not actually handle time. The answer implies that it does.

Answer (score 91):

The easiest way is to use lubridate:

```
library(lubridate)
prods.all$Date2 <- mdy(prods.all$Date2)
```

This function automatically returns objects of class `POSIXct` and will work with either factors or characters.

Comment: I will mention the existence of  things like ymd(), ymd_hms(), myd_hms(), etc. in that library to handle date and time fields together.
Awesome library btw. My hats off to you...

Comment: lubridate is an awesome package.  am still using it in 2018 and can't get enough of it.  There is a 'lubridate' cheat sheet at https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/raw/master/lubridate.pdf

Comment: @hadley When I am King, you shall be knighted.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the format you could use `anytime::anydate`, which tries to match to common formats:

```
library(anytime)

date <- c("01/01/2000 0:00:00", "Jan 1, 2000 0:00:00", "2000-Jan-01 0:00:00")

anydate(date)
[1] "2000-01-01" "2000-01-01" "2000-01-01"
```

Answer (score 0):

`library(lubridate)`
if your date format is like this '04/24/2017 05:35:00'then change it like below
`prods.all$Date2<-gsub("/","-",prods.all$Date2)`
 then change the date format
`parse_date_time(prods.all$Date2, orders="mdy hms")`

Comment: There's no need to change slashes to dashes, `parse_date_time` will parse it either way