# R formatting a date from a character mmm dd, yyyy to class date

Tags: r, date

I am trying to format a date from a character of form mmm dd, yyyy

I tried :

```
date1 <- "Dec 05, 2016"
date2 <- format(date1, format="%d %B %Y")
 class(date2)
 date2
```

but this does not work.
Thank you for any help.

I then tried as suggested:

```
date1 <- "Dec 05, 2016"
date2 <- format(as.Date(date1, "%b %d, %Y"), "%d %B %Y")
date2  <- as.Date(date2)

class(date2)
date2
```

but this still did not covert to  the class date but was class: character

This seems to work
ref:[Convert character to Date in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310326/convert-character-to-date-in-r)

```
library(lubridate)
date1 <- "Dec 05, 2016"
date2 <- mdy(date1)
class(date2)
date2
```

Comment: First you need to convert to `Date` class i.e. `format(as.Date(date1, "%b %d, %Y"))`

Answer (score 3):

We can convert to 'Date' class and then convert to the `format` of interest

```
format(as.Date(date1, "%b %d, %Y"), "%d %B %Y")
#[1] "05 December 2016"
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps but unfortunately I still get it as character class.date1 <- "Dec 05, 2016"
date2 <- format(as.Date(date1, "%b %d, %Y"), "%d %B %Y")
date2  <- as.Date(date2)

class(date2)
date2

Comment: I typed this above as it is not clear in the comment box

Comment: @adam.888  The `format` changes it to `character` class and `Date` class have only a single format i.e. `%Y-%m-%d` by design