# Converting Character Column to Date in R with Lubridate

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I have a character column called date that holds data such as "January 15, 2015"
I am trying to convert it to ymd format with the as.date function and I also tried the lubridate package.
I have tried methods such as:

```
shootings$Date <- ymd(shootings$Date))
```

and

```
shootings$Date <- as.Date(as.character(shootings$Date))
```

I Would like it to look like 2013-01-01 (ymd) if possible. but I keep getting a parsing issue or the data just goes in N/A. 
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `as.Date("January 15, 2015",format="%B %d, %Y")` see `?as.Date `and `?strptime` for help

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310326/convert-character-to-date-in-r

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you want is

```
mdy("January 15, 2015")
# [1] "2015-01-15"
```

The problem is that the function name has to correspond to your *input* format (mdy), not the desired *output* (ymd).

Comment: Great Thank you! it also gave me a good understanding of the code

Comment: @JuliusVainora Thanks for this! I tried this on my data with the format "12/18/1996 0:00:00" using ```mdy_hms()``` as that's my input format but my column was turned into all NAs. Can you help clarify as to why that is happening? I appreciate you taking the time!

Answer (score 5):

Using *anytime*:

```
# example data
x <- "January 15, 2015"

library(anytime)

anydate(x)
# [1] "2015-01-15"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can solve this with the lubridate library

```r
library(lubridate)

shootings %>% mdy(January 15, 2015)

output - 2015-01-15
```