# ggplot2 date in X axis is all combined

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am new to shiny and I have created an app however due to my large dataset all my date fields are squashed together and not readable for the user, I want to try and plot each specific date for the selected year (2014) along with each specific price that is linked to that date, selected year and country but I can not seem to do this easily without combining dates/years in the csv file which I do not want to do.

**GGPLOT Sample:**

[image: GGPLOT]

I have tried to play around with the aes code as shown below but even when the date field is allocated to the y axis the same thing happens.

```r
 library(shiny)
 library(ggplot2)
 pigs <- read.csv("pigs_data.csv")
 # Define UI for application 
 ui <- fluidPage(
 # Application title
 titlePanel("Pig Breeding"),
 sidebarLayout( 
 sidebarPanel(
 #Allows user to choose a year which changes the distribution of plot points
 selectInput(inputId = "year",
            label = "Choose a year:",
            choices = c(2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018),
            selectize = FALSE
            )
 ),
 # Show a plot of the generated distribution
 mainPanel(
 plotOutput("stats")
 )
  )
   )
 # Define server logic
 server <- function(input, output) { #for the selectInput you can use the following observeEvent(input$year, {
 output$stats <- renderPlot({
                    ggplot(pigs, 
                    aes(x = price, y = date, col = country)) + 
                    geom_jitter(width = 0.3) +
                    facet_grid(. ~input$year)
 })
 }
 # Run the application 
 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)'
```

I expect the app to show the individual dates (23/04/14) for each selected year (2014) along with a plot point for a specfic price (123.40) allocated to each country even if this means over plotting.

**Sample of dataset:**

[image: Sample of dataset]

Comment: It's squished because "date" column is not date

Comment: date column in the csv file or in the aes coding for the plot?

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310326/convert-character-to-date-in-r, also I would use `geom_line` since there are multiple groups and it's continuous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You date columns is still a string. In order to fix it you can try the following

`pigs <- read.csv("pigs_data.csv")
pigs$date <- as.Date(pigs$date, format="%d-%b-%y")`

which takes your string and converts it to a date column.

Comment: Hi Thomas, I get an error with this code:

Error: 'to' must be a finite number

Comment: My guess is, that there are NA's introduced when transforming the string to the date format. This can happen if the abbreveations do not match your local r installation.

Can you call the following code please and send me the output?

dput(pigs[1:5,])

It creates r Code that corresponds to the data. This way i can read it into my r session and see if i can reproduce the error.

Comment: I get the following error when I call this code:

> dput(pigs[1:5,])
Error in dput(pigs[1:5, ]) : object 'pigs' not found

Comment: structure(list(country = structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("Denmark", 
"EU Other", "France", "Germany", "Italy", "Poland", "Spain", 
"UK"), class = "factor"), date = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), price = c(75.51, 
76.45, 77.82, 78.33, 78.78)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Then it is definitely an error in the coercion.
Can you open the .csv file with a text editor of your choice and post a few lines of data please

Comment: country,date,price
Italy,30/11/15,75.51
Italy,07/12/15,76.45
Italy,14/12/15,77.82
Italy,21/12/15,78.33
Italy,23/11/15,78.78
Italy,28/12/15,81.53
Italy,16/11/15,81.6
Italy,04/01/16,81.6
Poland,30/11/15,82.25
Italy,11/01/16,82.93
Poland,07/12/15,83
Spain,07/12/15,84.36

Comment: So the format was different than i expected. Some programms like excel change the date into a more readable format.
This should work then.
pigs$date <- as.Date(pigs$date, format="%d/%m/%y")

Comment: just noticed that using this line of code (pigs <- read.csv("pigs_data.csv") pigs$date <- as.Date(pigs$date, format="%d/%m/%y")) stops the year select input from working, is there a way to get this connected again?