# From character to dates-time in R using decimal hours

Tags: r, date, time, data-conversion

I'm trying to convert characters to dates in R.

My data as the following format:

```
df <- data.frame(Date = c("23Jul2019 11:51:09 AM","23Jul2019 11:53:09 AM","19Jul2019 2:30:06 PM","01Aug2019 3:00:17 PM"))
```

Based on the solution found here:
[Convert character to Date in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310326/convert-character-to-date-in-r/4310474)

I could use

```
> as.Date(df$Date, "%d/%b/%Y %I:%M:%S %p") 
[1] NA NA NA NA
```

%I is for decimal hour (12h) and %p Locale-specific AM/PM (https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/dates.html) but for some reason, it returns NAs.

My goal is to sort the rows of a dataframe by date and time once dates in the character format converted to Dates in R.

What is the issue with the code I'm using?

Comment: Try this: `anytime::anydate(df$Date)`

Comment: It works to get the dates but not the time

Comment: Your format needs to match what you actually have in your data. Your dates aren't written with `"%d/%b/%Y"`, they're written with `"%d%b%Y"`

Comment: Also, `as.Date` is for dates, not date-times. You want a POSIX, not a Date object

Comment: Try `as.POSIXct(df$Date, format = "%d%b%Y %H:%M:%S %p")` You had a couple of errors in your format. The separating slashes and you defined hours as `%I` instead `%H`

Comment: Using the as.POSIXct(df$Date, format = "%d%b%Y %H:%M:%S %p") gives "2019-07-23 11:51:09 CEST" "2019-07-23 11:53:09 CEST" "2019-07-19 02:30:06 CEST" "2019-08-01 03:00:17 CEST" which does not allow me to distinguished between am and pm. There is why I used %I instead of %H

Comment: But the code works. Thanks

Comment: AFAIK Posix objects are going to put time in terms of 24 hours. I think you're confusing the date-time object and the way it's printed; you can have the information encoded as out of 24 hours (no am/pm), but then format it as a string out of 12 hours (with am/pm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve it

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date
df <- data.frame(Date = c("23Jul2019 11:51:09 AM","23Jul2019 11:53:09 AM","19Jul2019 2:30:06 PM","01Aug2019 3:00:17 PM"))

df %>% 
  mutate(r_date_time = Date %>% dmy_hms)
#>                    Date         r_date_time
#> 1 23Jul2019 11:51:09 AM 2019-07-23 11:51:09
#> 2 23Jul2019 11:53:09 AM 2019-07-23 11:53:09
#> 3  19Jul2019 2:30:06 PM 2019-07-19 14:30:06
#> 4  01Aug2019 3:00:17 PM 2019-08-01 15:00:17

dmy_hms(df$Date) 
#> [1] "2019-07-23 11:51:09 UTC" "2019-07-23 11:53:09 UTC"
#> [3] "2019-07-19 14:30:06 UTC" "2019-08-01 15:00:17 UTC"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: unfortunately I can't use the function:  because I can't install and use the tidyverse > library(tidyverse)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘vctrs’ 0.2.0 is already loaded, but >= 0.2.1 is required                                        > df %>% mutate(r_date_time = Date %>% dmy_hms)
Error in df %>% mutate(r_date_time = Date %>% dmy_hms) : 
  could not find function "%>%"

Comment: just lubridate will sove your core problem